# Using strings and variables in the iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, string, variables

I have a string here like so:

```
textbox.text =@"Your name is"
```

then I want to add right after "your name is" a variable that displays text.

so in Visual Basic I learned it like this:

```
textbox.text =@"Your name is" & variable1.
```

But now I can see that it doesn't work like that in Cocoa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
textbox.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your name is %@", variable1];
```

Read the documentation for `stringWithFormat:` to learn about string format specifiers. Basically, you have a format string that contains codes like `%@`, and the following arguments are put in place of those escape codes.

It has the same syntax as the old C-style `printf()` function. Cocoa's logging function, `NSLog()`, also works the same way.

If you need to combine a lot of strings together, try also reading about `NSMutableString`.

You could also do:

```
textbox.text = [@"Your name is " stringByAppendingString:variable1];
```

But if you have to concatenate more than two things, `stringWithFormat:` is much more concise.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSString's `stringByAppendingString:` method:

```
textbox.text = [@"Your name is" stringByAppendingString:variable1];
```